# combine union type object building

Tags: typescript

Brain hurts too much this morning and seems that I can't figure this out.

I commonly use own builder for each action, but trying to figure if it's possible to actually use just one builder.
Issue here is that based on type I'll add to "type" I can't figure how to select correct payload type (and return type).

```js
const typeArray = ['ONE', 'TWO'] as const;
type Types = typeof typeArray[number];
type Action<T> = Record<string, unknown> & {type: T};

interface ActionOne extends Action<'ONE'> {
    value1: string;
}
interface ActionTwo extends Action<'TWO'> {
    value2: string;
}
type AllActions = ActionOne | ActionTwo;

const actionBuilder = (type: Types, payload: Omit<AllActions, 'type'>) => ({
    ...payload,
    type,
});

actionBuilder('ONE',{value2: 'asd'}); // should give error
```

TS playround: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgQQE7oIbxgXhgG0ByAeQDkBRYgGhmIBUB1U4gXRiwhlEigG4AUAhQwGSZNwIjkIAGZwJGbPEJgArgFsARsnRshMmKmBQAluAA8DAHz4YAJWSh0AE0vR0ZsAHM66sABrMBAAdzA7ADIYAG8ZAC4xAF8hQW8oPTksYGRjUwswUjBc5AAPDLBXbhNzKzIqYjsYwRhWmAA3LAAbdWQARkTPbx8hJLSwDPQsnLzasAZQkBgyiqrZgstGFkbYlrbOnuQAJkGoL19R4QljLq6agql18CLcgB8n%20cXU3mhOfPAAELqMxdVx6ewACgSYgkEDoiBwXRAWFciVImjMUEsqFu93AcPoMkaAEp8HYIc02jAAHS0hHwJEomh7VoyZlJYmpbJzIEgsHoCH1ag0GIHXonehcVzEDn8GAAenlMAgAAsQOpQTAfGZ2iVMCB0EA)

Comment: I'm having trouble with solving this issue, possibly because of this; https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you aren't passing any type information into your `actionBuilder` function.

That is, when you say:

```
const actionBuilder = (type: Types, payload: Omit<AllActions, 'type'>) => ({
```

You aren't tell TypeScript to relate the `type` to the `payload`, you aren't providing any restrictions one how the type string should relate to the payload.

Generally this is where generic types are powerful and useful.

**First, note an issue with your `Action<T>` type:**

I've had to change your `Action<T>` type as well to just

```
type Action<T> =  {type: T};
```

The reason for this is that it [looks like a bug/feature with TypeScript where TypeScript will lose type information when you `Omit` a type that contains a `Record`.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36981)

In any case - I think the `Record<string, unknown>` is unnecessary - the `{type: T}` already indicates that the value is going to be some kind of JavaScript object.

ie:

```
type Foo = {
  type: 'one', 
}; 

const value: Foo = {
    type: 'one' as const, 
    extra: "extra values"  // TypeScript is fine with extra properties like this. 
}
```

**Solution 1 - Conditional Types**

```
const actionBuilder = <T extends Types, U extends (T extends 'ONE' ? ActionOne : ActionTwo)>(type: T, payload: Omit<U, 'type'>) => ({
    ...payload,
    type,
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgQQE7oIbxgXhgG0ByAeQDkBRYgGhmIBUB1U4gXRiwhlEigG4AUAhQwGSZNwIjkIAGZwJGbPEJgArgFsARsnRshg4RJipgUAJbgAPAwB8+GDADeMgFxiAvoZmnzVsFIwZAI-SxsyKmIHADInZ0EnJwA3LAAbdWQARg9odAswAHMhT0ECqD05LGBkMICGAHcQGGQADwqwABNuM3Cwa0YWaJdEpNSM5AAmXKh8opLjUVQ0tN6AqTrwINqAH02wRpBDXmhOf3AAIXULNM69R1sW9uQu7nEUCDoAVSeO7pgABQMX4vf6RagwAD8+22MA8a3AhwAlHYAe4xHREDg0iAsJ0PKRNBYoNYvnRiDJokj8A4AQkkjAAHTMrHwHF4mijJwyTmeJGGap9K43O7oAHg2jOcaZab0LidYh8-gwAD0KpgEAAFiB1LcYIULMlanp0CB0EZBEA)

**Explanation:**

Type `T` is just one of your `"ONE" | "TWO"` strings, simple enough. We then do a [*conditional type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) based on that value to determine what the second type should be.

But this is going to be a cumbersome solution if you have an `ActionThree`, `ActionFour` etc.

**Solution Two: Intersection Type**

The simpler solution is like this:

```
const actionBuilder = <T extends Types, U extends (AllActions & Action<T>)>(type: T, payload: Omit<U, 'type'>) => ({
    ...payload,
    type,
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgQQE7oIbxgXhgG0ByAeQDkBRYgGhmIBUB1U4gXRiwhlEigG4AUAhQwGSZNwIjkIAGZwJGbPEJgArgFsARsnRshg4RJipgUAJbgAPAwB8+GDADeMgFxiAvoZmnzVsFIwZAI-SxsyKmIHADInZ0EnJwA3LAAbdWQARg9odAswAHMhT0ECqD05LGBkMICGAHcQGGQADwqwABNuM3Cwa0YWaJdEpNSM5AAmXKh8opLjUVQ0tN6AqTrwINqAH02wRpBDXmhOf3AAIXULNM69R1sW9uQu7nEUCDoAVSeO7pgABTLVbnSAwOJrGz2ACUdgB7jEdEQODSICwnQ8pE0Fig1i+dGIMmi0PwDgBCSSMAAdDTkfBUeiaKMnDImZ5oYZqn0rjc7ugAZFqDRnONMtN6FxOsR2fwYAB6OUwCAACxA6luMEKFmStT06BA6CMgiAA)

**Explanation**

Here we say that the action needs to be an action of type T, but also it needs to be all actions.

TypeScript is going to look at the intersection of what's possible, and deduce that 'Ok, it has to be an ActionOne'.

Comment: this works nicely for current case, only thing I noticed that actionBuilder return type is not actually compatible with AllActions type

Comment: @Manda it looks ok to me? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgQQE7oIbxgXhgG0ByAeQDkBRYgGhmIBUB1U4gXRiwhlEigG4AUAhQwGSZNwIjkIAGZwJGbPEJgArgFsARsnRshg4RJipgUAJbgAPAwB8+GDADeMgFxiAvoZmnzVsFIwZAI-SxsyKmIHADInZ0EnJwA3LAAbdWQARg9odAswAHMhT0ECqD05LGBkMICGAHcQGGQADwqwABNuM3Cwa0YWaJdEpNSM5AAmXKh8opLjUVQ0tN6AqTrwINqAH02wRpBDXmhOf3AAIXULNM69R1sW9uQu7nEUCDoAVSeO7pgABTLVbnSAwOJrGz2ACUdgB7jEdEQODSICwnQ8pE0Fig1i+dGIMmi0PwDgBCSSMAAdDTkfBUeiaKMnDImZ5ocdwKdxpksjAPMDIWCCNU+lcbnd0ADItQaM4edkPMQuJ1iOyhCdYArJvzTCshRtRQFxbc9NKKLL5elMtN6Cq1RyYAB6J0wCAACxA6luMEKFmStT06BA6CMgiAA

Comment: yes!, found typo issue on my implementation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your codebase. I think now it is more readable and predictable:

```
enum Type {
    ONE,
    TWO,
};

type ActionPayload = Record<string, unknown>;

interface ActionOnePayload extends ActionPayload {
    value1: string;
}

interface ActionTwoPayload extends ActionPayload {
    value2: string;
}

type ActionPayloads = {
    [key in Type]: ActionPayload;
} & {
    [Type.ONE]: ActionOnePayload;
    [Type.TWO]: ActionTwoPayload;
}

type Action<T extends Type> = {
    type: T;
    payload: ActionPayloads[T];
}

function actionBuilder<T extends Type>(type: T, payload: ActionPayloads[T]): Action<T> {
    return {
        payload,
        type,
    };
}

actionBuilder(Type.ONE, {value2: 'asd'}); // should give error
```